# Yasnippet expand snippet automatically instead of prompting possible completions

Tags: completion, yasnippet

I have two snippets:

- e[TAB] expands to $ $1 $ $0 ($1 and $0 are placeholders);
- emph expands to \emph{$0} ($0 is a placeholder, this is a default snippet I suppose)

I'm writing a lot of equations between text in Auctex and whenever I type "e[TAB]" I want yasnippet to expand the first snippet directly. Instead, what it does is to prompt a list of possible completions, which in this case is those two snippets. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as [#369 "Built-in templates not getting overridden by local templates when keys are identical, but names differ"](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/issues/369).  As you might be able to guess from that title, you can make your snippet have the same name as the builtin one to override it, rather than have both.  Note that any snippet you make with the same `name` field will override the builtin.  You don't have to make your `e` snippet specifically have the same name.